# How set CSS atyle attributes of controls via request.form["x"] method in aspx code behind?

Tags: asp.net, client-side, server-side

I want set CSS style attributes of some controls (like input text) for example by `Request.Form["x"]` method in aspx page .cs code ,runat="server" is set for that controls and them is known in intellisense of .cs and them didn't find by `form1.FindControl("x")` (for some my reason that depend on jQuery issue) but i want set their CSS style in another syntax.
Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a client html control, use a server side control with a css class name. Then modify the definition of the CSS class in the code behind.

In your aspx:

```
<style type="text/css" runat="server" id="htmlCss"></style>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" CssClass="myCssClass"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string css = @".myCssClass { background-color:yellow; }";
    htmlCss.InnerHtml = css;
}
```

All the control needs to know is the styles are in "myCssClass". In Page Load you decide what the styles are going to be.